# How to add downloaded plugins into grails project using STS Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-plugin

I wonder, Is there any way to add downloaded plugins to project using STS(Sprint tool suite) like we have in intellj ide (add custom plugins) http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Managing_Grails_plugins

for example i have downloaded jasper plugins how would i add it into my grail project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your *BuildConfig.groovy* file you can add the plugin.

Merge the follwing in to the *grails.project.dependency.resolution* closure:

```
repositories{
  mavenRepo "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/"
}

plugins {
 compile ":jasper:1.5.3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i am doing that only to add plugins in my grails app, but instead of doing it manually don't we have a way in STS like netbeans or intellj..

Comment: The recommended way to install plugins now is the method above instead of using the grails install-plugin which is what the IDEs are doing.